# fastest way to find element position using javascript?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I've used jquery's offset().top, but when running it 4000 times in a loop the browsers freezes for a few seconds. Is there a faster way to get this?

This is happening on the iPAD the desktop is faster.

```
for (counter=1; counter<4000; counter++)
{
   yPos = Math.round($("#star_"+counter).offset().top);
```

Comment: _4000 times_? Why?

Comment: Please post a more complete code sample.  Advice I might give you could include caching the value, but I can't tell if that's appropriate with just that single line.

Comment: A browser can only execute javascript statements one by one. Then, if you have a loop, while browser is executing that loop it doesn't execute anything else at that time. So `Math.round($("#box").offset().top)` won't change during the loop, so you don't need to check it 4000 times.

Comment: Its a star filled sky animation. The number of stars are currently set to 4000 but could be more. The positions are incremented for each star between 0 and 5 randomly to give a feeling of depth.

Comment: You're not creating multiple elements with the same id of `box`, are you?

Comment: Sorry I didnt post the entire code. The stars have an ID $("#star"+counter). that I use inside a for loop.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`.offset().top` always returns an integer, so rounding it is unnecessary. Furthermore, you can cache the jQuery object for efficiency:

```
$box = $('#box');
// start your loop here
    yPos = $box.offset().top;
// end loop
```

**UPDATE**

Assign a class to each star so you don't have to keep creating new jQuery objects:

```
$('.stars').each(function(i,el) { 
    var yPos = this.offsetTop; 
});
```

http://api.jquery.com/each

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/DOM/element.scrollTop

Comment: He could possibly cache yPos as well.  We can't tell because he posted a single line of code.

Comment: Sorry for posting only one line of code. I loop through the stars using  $("#star"+counter). in a for loop. The box is the div container of the stars. Should have been more clear.

Answer (score 0):

You could also not use jQuery...

```
var element = document.getElementById("box");
var top = element.offsetTop;
while (element.parentNode) {

    element = element.parentNode;
    top += element.offsetTop;

}
console.log(top);
```

jQuery does a bit of extra work getting the div, than pure javascript. So if speed is an issue here, you should use pure javascript.

But if these are stars in a sky you could just use offsetTop and be sure that they are contained in a div that fills the whole screen:

```
document.getElementById("box").offsetTop;
```

But I also guess that you do some kind of calculation to put the stars there in the first place. You should create an Array of the stars, referencing the divs. Something like:

```
var stars = [];

for (var x = 0; x < 4000; x++) {

    var star = document.createElement("DIV");
    var position = setStarPosition(star);
    stars.push({

        star: star,
        position: position

    });
    document.body.appendChild(star);

}

function setStarPosition(star) {

    // Some positioning code which stores left and top position in variables

    return {

        left: left,
        top: top

    }

}
```

When you want to manipulate the stars you go through the array, which has the position and a reference to the div.

Referencing divs inside the javascript environment (f.ex. in an array) is A LOT faster than referencing them in the DOM.

Comment: You might also want to check for isNaN( element.offsetTop ) within the while loop

Answer (score 0):

Instead of this:

```
for (counter=1; counter<4000; counter++) {
    yPos = Math.round($("#star_"+counter).offset().top);
    // etc
}
```

Assign a class to all stars (let's call it class="starry") and do this:

```
var cacheStars = $(".starry");
```

This never needs updating unless you add or remove stars, in which case you can refresh it.  Then your loop becomes:

```
cacheStars.each(function(index, element) {
    ypos = element.offsetTop;
});
```